# How to display a plot in a new tab in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, metafor

I have a dataset for a meta-analysis study, and my code does a good job in displaying the forest plots. However, I would like to display the diagnostic plots in a new tab, using an action button in the original (first) tab.

To be more specific, I have an action button in the original tab, which creates a plot. I would like to have a second tab, without any action button, that only displays this plot, and updates whenever the action button in the original tab is activated.

As an example, you can use the simple app below which displays the plot in the same page. It's not the code for my project, but since I cannot share my datasets, I would appreciate it if you could help me implement it using this sample code/data.

```
# A basic shiny app with a plotOutput
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("newplot", "New plot")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      input$newplot
      # Add a little noise to the cars data
      cars2 <- cars + rnorm(nrow(cars))
      plot(cars2)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: There is no `tabsetPanel` or similar in the code you shared. Please provide us with a proper example.

Comment: @ismirsehregal I will try! But since I'm very new to Shiny, it is difficult to provide the reproducible example for me. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tabsetPanel to create multiple tabsets.

I moved the button to the main tab.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        h2("I am a sidebar")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Button", actionButton("newplot", "New plot")),
          tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot"))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      input$newplot
      # Add a little noise to the cars data
      cars2 <- cars + rnorm(nrow(cars))
      plot(cars2)
    })
  }
)
```